# Disable rapid click on item in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment class that extends ListFragment. The `onListItemClick()` is as follows -

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        MyAdapter.MergedData item = adapter.getItem(position);

        Intent intent = MyActivity.createIntent(mActivity, item);
        startActivity(mActivity, intent);
    }
```

The requirement is I need to disable rapid click on the list item. How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following...

```
/**
 * used to prevent the double click on some view
 *
 * @param view a view whick is required prevention.
 */
public static void preventDoubleClick(final View view) {
    view.setEnabled(false);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }, 2000); //set this based on your requirement
}
```

Call this method on

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    //used to prevent the rapid clicks....
    preventDoubleClick(v);

    MyAdapter.MergedData item = adapter.getItem(position);

    Intent intent = MyActivity.createIntent(mActivity, item);
    startActivity(mActivity, intent);
}
```

And you are done!

Answer (score 0):

You may disable the view for a while I guess, use this function:-

```
public static void preventDoubleClick(final View v) {
    v.setEnabled(false);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            v.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }, 1000); // Will disable view for 1 sec.
}
```